# Reproducing industrial system colors (RAL, NCS, Pantone)

Tags: color-conversion, painting, palette

Assuming I have access to equipment that gives me ability to measure precise amounts of fluids - is it possible to reproduce colours of any well-known system (like RAL, NCS...) using avialable pigments or paints?
My ultimate goal is to reproduce digital photos using acrylic paints on canvas. Using posterisation I want to reduce palette to resonable amount of colours then match them with one of existing systems and "produce" matching colour.

I am very aware of limitiations of this approach and I know that matching digital colours with real ones is challenging but seems that is the easiest/most simple option- rely on standarized colours.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/136914/discussion-on-question-by-mactok-reproducing-industrial-system-colors-ral-ncs).